# How to calculate the confidence interval around a ratio, when the margin of error is known for the two numbers

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, ratio

I've got this table from the U.S. Census Bureau's American Community Survey. The `moe` column contains the 90% C.I.

```
  variable estimate   moe
1 total      232176  4317
2 owner       92982  3261
3 renter     139194  4309
```

Owners make up an estimated 40% of the total `(92982/232176 = 0.400)`. I'd like to calculate the 90% confidence interval for that proportion. How can I do that, given the margins of error for the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Were you aware the ACS documentation explains what to do and gives examples?  It applies the *Delta Method.*  It also describes a more accurate method based on "variance replicate estimates."  See https://www.census.gov/data/academy/webinars/2020/calculating-margins-of-error-acs.html for instance.